# execute IMMEDIATE plsql

Tags: oracle, plsql

I encountered the following error:

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

while trying to build a plsql script:

```
   declare 
    yearmonth varchar2(20) := &yearmonth ; 
    begin 
    execute IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE tbl_board_new_method AS  
    with a as (  
    select u.*,case when ooo.terminal_number is not null then "BOX" else "NOBOX" end ISBOX  from (
    select q.*,
    CASE WHEN   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) IS NOT NULL AND  substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)  <  coalesce(   substr(i.install_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date )  THEN 
    coalesce(   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  ELSE 
    coalesce(q.install_date,
    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8),
    substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8))  END f_install_date, 
    nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) f_disable_date,
    q.pos_model pos_model1,
    q.pos_brand pos_brand1,
    q.pos_brand_model pos_brand_model1 ,
    CASE
      WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
      (:COMBO,
      "DIALUP",
      "LAN",
    "BRANCH") THEN
    "POS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("PCPOS", "TYPICAL") THEN
    "PCPOS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("MPOS(BT/INTERNET)",
    "MPOS") THEN
    "MPOS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) =
    "GPRS" THEN
    "GPRS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) =
    "IPG" THEN
    "IPG"
    ELSE
    "POS"
    END
    END
    END
    END
    
    from trg.tbl_merchant_info q
    left join trg.mvw_terminal_indicators i  on (q.terminal_number = i.terminal_number)
    where coalesce(q.install_date,
    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8),
    substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)) is not null
    and 
    CASE WHEN   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) IS NOT NULL AND  substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) <    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8)  THEN 
    coalesce(   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  ELSE 
    coalesce(q.install_date,
    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8),
    substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)) END   <=  '||yearmonth||'||30
    and (nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) is null OR  nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) >='||yearmonth||'||01
    ) 
    and (trim(q.pos_model) is null or
    not
    (upper(q.pos_model) like "%MPOS%"  ))
    --- union 
    UNION 
    select q.*,
    CASE WHEN   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) IS NOT NULL AND  substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)  <    coalesce(   substr(i.install_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date )  THEN 
    coalesce(   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  ELSE 
    coalesce(q.install_date,
    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8),
    substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8))  END f_install_date,
    nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) f_disable_date,
    q.pos_model pos_model1,
    q.pos_brand pos_brand1,
    q.pos_brand_model pos_brand_model1 ,
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("COMBO",
    "POS",
    "DIALUP",
    "LAN",
    "BRANCH") THEN
    "POS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("PCPOS", "TYPICAL") THEN
    "PCPOS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("MPOS(BT/INTERNET)",
    "MPOS") THEN
    "MPOS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) =
    "GPRS" THEN
    "GPRS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) =
    "IPG" THEN
    "IPG"
    ELSE
    "POS"
    END
    END
    END
    END
    END FINAL_POS_MODEL
    from   trg.tbl_merchant_info q  
    left join trg.mvw_terminal_indicators i
    on (q.terminal_number = i.terminal_number)
    WHERE q.terminal_number IN (SELECT terminalno FROM trg.fct_total_aggrigate_daily d  WHERE substr(trn_date,0,6) = substr('||yearmonth||',0,6) )  
    ) u left join (select * from  trg.mvw_terminal_indicators  ooo 
    where   ooo.box_install is not null and (box_uninstall is null or  substr(ooo.box_uninstall,0,8)>= '||yearmonth||'||01) )  ooo on (ooo.terminal_number = u.terminal_number )
    a.terminal_number = t111.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = tt211.terminalno (+) and 
    a.terminal_number = ttt311.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = tttt411.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = ttttt511.terminalno (+)
    )
    --, pre AS (
    select terminalid, 
    case when m.scale_install is not null then 1 else 0 end   scale_install  ,
    yearmonth
    from p  left join  trg.mvw_terminal_indicators m on (p.terminal_number = m.terminal_number)';
    end ;
```

Comment: That's just too complex query (at least, for me). Instead of executing it, store it into a local variable and display it (using dbms_output.put_line) on the screen. Then copy/paste it and run it in a tool which will point to the error. What I saw, was that you referenced some `:COMBO` thing - that certainly won't work so you'll probably want to remove a colon sign. Other than that, well, I can't run that code as I don't have your tables.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but because there is a lot of code, I can not complete it. I removed the sign: but it is not the reason. What is your opinion?

_Littlefoot

Comment: Do you think that the parts in the bet and the character inside this symbol "" are correct?

Comment: declare 
yearmonth varchar2(20) := &yearmonth ; 
begin 
execute IMMEDIATE 'CREATE TABLE tbl_board_new_method AS  
with a as (  
select u.*,case when ooo.terminal_number is not null then "BOX" else "NOBOX" end ISBOX  from (
select q.*

Comment: Takes the error from line 4 from the create table

Comment: @Littlefoot
plz help me

Comment: As I said: make sure that CREATE TABLE statement is correctly written. As it is complex, do it slowly, step-by-step, test frequently. Once you make it work (outside of PL/SQL), then re-use it in dynamic SQL.

Comment: I use code outside of declare and it works but when I try to use it in a variable this error message is received

Comment: @Littlefoot
tanq bro

Comment: Hm, I don't think it works. Strings should be enclosed into **single**, not double quotes. As it is difficult to work them in dynamic SQL (as you have to *escape* them), I'd suggest you to switch to the q-quoting mechanism which will let you use single quotes "normally" (without escaping them).

Comment: thank you
If I give you the code, you run it, there is no problem, because it does not reach the run and the error is received, there is no need for tables.
I'm asking you to change my code to make it work, but I'm extremely grateful
@Littlefoot

Comment: Pull out the code, replace any doubled single-quotes with single single quotes, replace any variables with values and try to run it ad-hoc outside your procedure. That will enable you to find the error much more easily. Once you correct it, replace those single single-quotes with doubled-up single quotes and pop it back in.

Comment: Oh, and why is this in PL/SQL in the first place? You have an anonymous PL/SQL block opened by DECLARE, so it isn't a stored procedure. It's not adding any PL/SQL processing of any kind either. Why not just do the CTAS operation as normal SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Part of a problem are double quated strings within sql which are considered as identifiers.
Here is a small test.

```sql
-- test data
CREATE TABLE a_table (ID Number(3), COL1 VarChar2(20), COL2 VarChar2(20));
INSERT INTO a_table VALUES(1, 'AAA', 'BBB');
INSERT INTO a_table VALUES(1, 'BBB', 'CCC');
INSERT INTO a_table VALUES(1, 'CCC', 'AAA');
--
--  Creating sql comands with double and single quated strings
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
Declare
    sq      VarChar2(1) := '''';
    myID    Number(3) := 1;
    mySql   VarChar2(1000);
    mySql2  VarChar2(1000);
Begin
    mySql := 'Select COL1, COL2  From a_table Where COL1 IN("AAA") And ID = 1';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mySql);
    --
    mySQL2 := 'Select COL1, COL2  From a_table Where COL1 IN(' || sq || 'AAA' || sq || ') And ID = 1';
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(mySql2);
End;
/
--
--  double quated string in sql throws an error 
Select COL1, COL2  From a_table Where COL1 IN("AAA") And ID = 1
--      SQL Error: ORA-00904: "AAA": invalid identifier
--
-- this one works
Select COL1, COL2  From a_table Where COL1 IN('AAA') And ID = 1
--      COL1                 COL2               
--      -------------------- --------------------
--      AAA                  BBB
```

Your query is to  big for me to analyze but most of the problems could be double quotes. In the test a variable named sq is  used to hold a single quote ('''' --> four of them are represented as a single quote) and then, when composing the sql command, the variable is used to put the single quote into the command  where there is a value of type varchar. Otherwise Oracle tries to find identifier. Regards...

ADDITION:
Beside double quotes there are some other problems with the code.
I took it from your question, and structured it a bit to make it more readable.
Problems are commented in the code below there are some code missing, some wrong and some I couldn't get to understand.
Here is the structured version and problems are in lines [26, 45, 107, 116, 124, 125] and in the main SELECT [lines 128 - 138]
You will know things that I didn't catch and maybe make it work...

```sql
CREATE TABLE 
    tbl_board_new_method AS 
        
    with a as 
        (  
            Select 
                u.*,
                CASE WHEN ooo.terminal_number Is Not Null THEN "BOX" ELSE "NOBOX" END as ISBOX  
            From 
                (
                    Select 
                        q.*,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) IS NOT NULL AND  substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)  <  coalesce(substr(i.install_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date )  
                            THEN coalesce(substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  
                        ELSE 
                            coalesce(q.install_date, substr(i.install_date, 0, 8), substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8))  
                        END as F_INSTALL_DATE, 
                        --
                        Nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) as F_DISABLE_DATE,
                        q.pos_model as POS_MODEL1,
                        q.pos_brand as POS_BRAND1,
                        q.pos_brand_model as POS_BRAND_MODEL1,
                        --
                        CASE
                          WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN(:COMBO, "DIALUP", "LAN", "BRANCH") THEN "POS"              -- here was :COMBO -> I put "COMBO" as it is in second (unioned) query
                        ELSE
                            CASE
                                WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN("PCPOS", "TYPICAL") THEN "PCPOS"
                            ELSE
                                CASE
                                    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN("MPOS(BT/INTERNET)", "MPOS") THEN "MPOS"
                                ELSE
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) = "GPRS" THEN "GPRS"
                                    ELSE
                                        CASE
                                            WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) = "IPG" THEN "IPG"
                                        ELSE
                                            "POS"
                                        END
                                    END
                                END
                            END
                        END  as FINAL_POS_MODEL         -- this row was missing
                    From 
                        trg.tbl_merchant_info q
                    Left Join 
                        trg.mvw_terminal_indicators i ON(q.terminal_number = i.terminal_number)
                    Where 
                        coalesce(q.install_date, substr(i.install_date, 0, 8), substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)) is not null And 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) Is Not Null And substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) < substr(i.install_date, 0, 8)  
                            THEN coalesce(substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  
                        ELSE 
                            coalesce(q.install_date, substr(i.install_date, 0, 8), substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)) END <= ' || yearmonth || ' || 30 And
                            (
                                nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) is null OR  nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) >= '|| yearmonth ||' || 01
                            ) And 
                            (trim(q.pos_model) is null 
                          OR 
                            Not (Upper(q.pos_model) like "%MPOS%"))
                    --
                    --
                  UNION 
                    --
                    --
                    Select 
                        q.*,
                        CASE 
                            WHEN substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) Is Not Null And  substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) < coalesce(substr(i.install_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date )  
                            THEN coalesce(substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  
                        ELSE 
                            coalesce(q.install_date, substr(i.install_date, 0, 8), substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8))  
                        END as F_INSTALL_DATE, 
                        Nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) as F_DISABLE_DATE,
                        q.pos_model as POS_MODEL1,
                        q.pos_brand as POS_BRAND1,
                        q.pos_brand_model as POS_BRAND_MODEL1 ,
                        CASE
                            WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN("COMBO", "POS", "DIALUP", "LAN", "BRANCH") THEN "POS"
                        ELSE
                            CASE
                                WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN("PCPOS", "TYPICAL") THEN "PCPOS"
                            ELSE
                                CASE
                                    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN("MPOS(BT/INTERNET)", "MPOS") THEN "MPOS"
                                ELSE
                                    CASE
                                        WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) = "GPRS" THEN "GPRS"
                                    ELSE
                                        CASE
                                            WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) = "IPG" THEN "IPG"
                                        ELSE
                                            "POS"
                                        END
                                    END
                                END
                            END
                        END as FINAL_POS_MODEL
                    From   
                        trg.tbl_merchant_info q  
                    Left Join 
                        trg.mvw_terminal_indicators i ON(q.terminal_number = i.terminal_number)
                    Where 
                        q.terminal_number IN(   SELECT terminalno 
                                                FROM trg.fct_total_aggrigate_daily -- d -> table alias d excluded as not needed nor used in subquery
                                                WHERE substr(trn_date, 0, 6) = substr(' || yearmonth || ', 0, 6)
                                            )  
                ) u 
            Left Join 
                (
                    select 
                        * 
                    from  
                        trg.mvw_terminal_indicators ooo         -- ooo here as table alias is the same as the whole subquery alias  --> it can stay (used in where) but confusing 
                    Where 
                        ooo.box_install Is Not Null And 
                        (
                            box_uninstall Is Null OR substr(ooo.box_uninstall,0,8) >= ' || yearmonth || ' || 01
                        ) 
                )  ooo ON(ooo.terminal_number = u.terminal_number) 
        -- there should probably be WHERE clause here but I don't know what are next 2 lines - using alias [a] before it was created !?? (closing bracket in third line below ends creation of CTE named a) 
            a.terminal_number = t111.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = tt211.terminalno (+) and 
            a.terminal_number = ttt311.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = tttt411.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = ttttt511.terminalno (+)
        )
-- after end of creation of CTE named [a] (line 126) --> below should be the main select but you are selecting FROM p (what is p) joined with trg.mvw_terminal_indicators (nothing selected from [a])
SELECT 
    terminalid, 
    CASE 
        WHEN m.scale_install Is Not Null THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
    END as SCALE_INSTALL,
    yearmonth       
FROM 
    p  -- what is p   -->   you are not selecting anything from (CTE) named [a]
LEFT JOIN  
    trg.mvw_terminal_indicators m ON(p.terminal_number = m.terminal_number)
```

There is still the double quote problem but that can be solved using any text editor.
Declare variable to hold the sql code string, declare sq variable and put '''' as a value of it and replace ["] with [' || sq || ']. Then print the code (DBMS_OUTPUT) copy it, inspect it and run it. There will probably be some more corrections to do but you will get the err message what and where is the problem.

Comment: I could do the transformation for you but only after you give me instructions what to do with problematic lines of code stated in the addition.

Answer (score 0):

you can use quoted string instead, like this:

```
declare 
    yearmonth varchar2(20) := &yearmonth ; 
    begin 
    execute IMMEDIATE q'[CREATE TABLE tbl_board_new_method AS  
    with a as (  
    select u.*,case when ooo.terminal_number is not null then "BOX" else "NOBOX" end ISBOX  from (
    select q.*,
    CASE WHEN   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) IS NOT NULL AND  substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)  <  coalesce(   substr(i.install_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date )  THEN 
    coalesce(   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  ELSE 
    coalesce(q.install_date,
    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8),
    substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8))  END f_install_date, 
    nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) f_disable_date,
    q.pos_model pos_model1,
    q.pos_brand pos_brand1,
    q.pos_brand_model pos_brand_model1 ,
    CASE
      WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
      (:COMBO,
      "DIALUP",
      "LAN",
    "BRANCH") THEN
    "POS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("PCPOS", "TYPICAL") THEN
    "PCPOS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("MPOS(BT/INTERNET)",
    "MPOS") THEN
    "MPOS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) =
    "GPRS" THEN
    "GPRS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) =
    "IPG" THEN
    "IPG"
    ELSE
    "POS"
    END
    END
    END
    END
    
    from trg.tbl_merchant_info q
    left join trg.mvw_terminal_indicators i  on (q.terminal_number = i.terminal_number)
    where coalesce(q.install_date,
    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8),
    substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)) is not null
    and 
    CASE WHEN   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) IS NOT NULL AND  substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) <    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8)  THEN 
    coalesce(   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  ELSE 
    coalesce(q.install_date,
    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8),
    substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)) END   <=  '||yearmonth||'||30
    and (nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) is null OR  nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) >='||yearmonth||'||01
    ) 
    and (trim(q.pos_model) is null or
    not
    (upper(q.pos_model) like "%MPOS%"  ))
    --- union 
    UNION 
    select q.*,
    CASE WHEN   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) IS NOT NULL AND  substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8)  <    coalesce(   substr(i.install_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date )  THEN 
    coalesce(   substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8) , q.install_date,  substr(i.install_date, 0, 8))  ELSE 
    coalesce(q.install_date,
    substr(i.install_date, 0, 8),
    substr(i.min_trn_date, 0, 8))  END f_install_date,
    nvl(q.disable_date, substr(i.disable_date, 0, 8)) f_disable_date,
    q.pos_model pos_model1,
    q.pos_brand pos_brand1,
    q.pos_brand_model pos_brand_model1 ,
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("COMBO",
    "POS",
    "DIALUP",
    "LAN",
    "BRANCH") THEN
    "POS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("PCPOS", "TYPICAL") THEN
    "PCPOS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) IN
    ("MPOS(BT/INTERNET)",
    "MPOS") THEN
    "MPOS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) =
    "GPRS" THEN
    "GPRS"
    ELSE
    CASE
    WHEN UPPER(q.pos_model) =
    "IPG" THEN
    "IPG"
    ELSE
    "POS"
    END
    END
    END
    END
    END FINAL_POS_MODEL
    from   trg.tbl_merchant_info q  
    left join trg.mvw_terminal_indicators i
    on (q.terminal_number = i.terminal_number)
    WHERE q.terminal_number IN (SELECT terminalno FROM trg.fct_total_aggrigate_daily d  WHERE substr(trn_date,0,6) = substr('||yearmonth||',0,6) )  
    ) u left join (select * from  trg.mvw_terminal_indicators  ooo 
    where   ooo.box_install is not null and (box_uninstall is null or  substr(ooo.box_uninstall,0,8)>= '||yearmonth||'||01) )  ooo on (ooo.terminal_number = u.terminal_number )
    a.terminal_number = t111.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = tt211.terminalno (+) and 
    a.terminal_number = ttt311.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = tttt411.terminalno (+) and a.terminal_number = ttttt511.terminalno (+)
    )
    --, pre AS (
    select terminalid, 
    case when m.scale_install is not null then 1 else 0 end   scale_install  ,
    yearmonth
    from p  left join  trg.mvw_terminal_indicators m on (p.terminal_number = m.terminal_number)]';
    end ;
```

[Oracle documentation here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_CIREYU9EA54EOKQ7LAMZKRF6P.html)